# Macbook Pro Mid 2014 stuttering and small lag spikes @ 4K 30Hz with HDMI 2.0/1.4b

Tags: video, hdmi

So the limit of the Macbook Pro mid 2014 is 3840x2160 at 30 Hz through HDMI 2.0 (I guess it's only 1.4b). When I fire up VLC and look on my Macbook, the image is clear and there is no stutering what so ever. It runs butter smooth. When I look at my TV, however, the quality is still very, very good, but the video stutters all the time. It's like a bungee/elastic effect when there's a panorama shot, and when there's a rolling shot going very fast, it's like watching 10 FPS clips.

I can see my Macbook Pro uses the integrated 750M graphics card, and it does get quite hot.

What's the issue here?

Comment: Same issue but with MBP 2017 and even through USB-C to DisplayPort 1.2 cable (which supports 4K@60Hz). I have micro-stutter for the mouse every few seconds. Let me know if you found the solution

Answer (score 1):

I have a new 15 inch MacBook Pro. it has 4 thunderbolt ports on the sides. 2 on each side. no USB ports. so I bought an adapter for it. its  called a lention and has 4 different ports,3 usb an one lightening so I could plug my mouse in to it.i  began experiencing stuttering on my games and video. every 4 seconds it would stutter. my frame rates were going from 60fps to 30 fps and back an forth causing the stuttering.i unplugged it(the lention adapter) from my MacBook Pro an stuttering stopped!I went too the apple store an bought a different one(white one with just 1 USB port)an the stuttering has stopped completely.just wanted to share this in hopes it will help.